# How to add Google API Key in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an excel file that I am trying to build with Google Maps API so I can tell the distance between addresses. Due to limitations, I can only run a few rows at a time. I do have an API key, but cannot figure out where to apply the key. Here is my code that I am editing from some open source online. The code works if I do one at a time, but with hundreds of records, I need to copy and paste a large amount of rows. So I have a license key for Google. Could someone help me understand where to apply the key?

Thank you in advance.

```
              Const strUnits = "imperial" ' imperial/metric (miles/km)

            Function CleanHTML(ByVal strHTML)
            'Helper function to clean HTML instructions
            Dim strInstrArr1() As String
            Dim strInstrArr2() As String
            Dim s As Integer

            strInstrArr1 = Split(strHTML, "<")
            For s = LBound(strInstrArr1) To UBound(strInstrArr1)
               strInstrArr2 = Split(strInstrArr1(s), ">")
               If UBound(strInstrArr2) > 0 Then
                    strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(1)
               Else
                    strInstrArr1(s) = strInstrArr2(0)
               End If
            Next

            CleanHTML = Join(strInstrArr1)
            End Function

            Public Function formatGoogleTime(ByVal lngSeconds As Double)
            'Helper function. Google returns the time in seconds, so this converts it into time format hh:mm

            Dim lngMinutes As Long
            Dim lngHours As Long

            lngMinutes = Fix(lngSeconds / 60)
            lngHours = Fix(lngMinutes / 60)
            lngMinutes = lngMinutes - (lngHours * 60)

            formatGoogleTime = Format(lngHours, "00") & ":" & Format(lngMinutes, "00")
            End Function




            Function gglDirectionsResponse(ByVal strStartLocation, ByVal strEndLocation, ByRef strTravelTime, ByRef strDistance, ByRef strInstructions, Optional ByRef strError = "") As Boolean
            On Error GoTo errorHandler
            ' Helper function to request and process XML generated by Google Maps.

            Dim strURL As String
            Dim objXMLHttp As Object
            Dim objDOMDocument As Object
            Dim nodeRoute As Object
            Dim lngDistance As Long

            Set objXMLHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            Set objDOMDocument = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")

            strStartLocation = Replace(strStartLocation, " ", "+")
            strEndLocation = Replace(strEndLocation, " ", "+")

            strURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml" & _
                        "?origin=" & strStartLocation & _
                        "&destination=" & strEndLocation & _
                        "&sensor=false" & _
                        "&units=" & strUnits   'Sensor field is required by google and indicates whether a Geo-sensor is being used by the device making the request

            'Send XML request
            With objXMLHttp
                .Open "GET", strURL, False
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
                .Send
                objDOMDocument.LoadXML .ResponseText
            End With

            With objDOMDocument
                If .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text = "OK" Then
                    'Get Distance
                    lngDistance = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/value").Text ' Retrieves distance in meters
                    Select Case strUnits
                        Case "imperial": strDistance = Round(lngDistance * 0.00062137, 1)  'Convert meters to miles
                        Case "metric": strDistance = Round(lngDistance / 1000, 1) 'Convert meters to miles
                    End Select

                    'Get Travel Time
                    strTravelTime = .SelectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/value").Text  'returns in seconds from google
                    strTravelTime = formatGoogleTime(strTravelTime) 'converts seconds to hh:mm

                    'Get Directions
                    For Each nodeRoute In .SelectSingleNode("//route/leg").ChildNodes
                        If nodeRoute.BaseName = "step" Then
                            strInstructions = strInstructions & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("html_instructions").Text & " - " & nodeRoute.SelectSingleNode("distance/text").Text & vbCrLf
                        End If
                    Next

                    strInstructions = CleanHTML(strInstructions) 'Removes MetaTag information from HTML result to convert to plain text.

                Else
                    strError = .SelectSingleNode("//status").Text
                    GoTo errorHandler
                End If
            End With

            gglDirectionsResponse = True
            GoTo CleanExit


                If strError = "" Then strError = Err.Description
                strDistance = -1
                strTravelTime = "00:00"
                strInstructions = ""
                gglDirectionsResponse = False

                Set objDOMDocument = Nothing
                Set objXMLHttp = Nothing

            End Function


            Function getGoogleTravelTime(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
            'Returns the journey time between strFrom and strTo

            Dim strTravelTime As String
            Dim strDistance As String
            Dim strInstructions As String
            Dim strError As String

            If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
                getGoogleTravelTime = strTravelTime
            Else
                getGoogleTravelTime = strError
            End If

            End Function

            Function getGoogleDistance(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
            'Returns the distance between strFrom and strTo
            'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
            'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

            Dim strTravelTime As String
            Dim strDistance As String
            Dim strError As String
            Dim strInstructions As String

            If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
                getGoogleDistance = strDistance
            Else
                getGoogleDistance = strError
            End If

            End Function

            Function getGoogleDirections(ByVal strFrom, ByVal strTo) As String
            'Returns the directions between strFrom and strTo
            'where strFrom/To are address search terms recognisable by Google
            'i.e. Postcode, address etc.

            Dim strTravelTime As String
            Dim strDistance As String
            Dim strError As String
            Dim strInstructions As String

            If gglDirectionsResponse(strFrom, strTo, strTravelTime, strDistance, strInstructions, strError) Then
                getGoogleDirections = strInstructions
            Else
                getGoogleDirections = strError
            End If

            End Function
```

Comment: This is probably more code than is necessary to include to receive an answer

Comment: It looks like you do have a key in the posted code.  Google's services have a quota and a rate limit, which are you encountering? Have you enabled billing with a credit card for that key?

Comment: Thank you both. I do have a corporate key that is enabled. My challenge here is that I don't have the key being called, so I am sure I am hitting the free version quota. Would there be a way you can see how I would append my key so that I don't hit up against the free version quota's?

Comment: Sorry, let me add, what you see here was my attempt to add the JSON call vs. the XML call. But that throws an error. So the commented out XML call is what is actually running.

Comment: I just edited the code to show how it looks while functioning. This is where I would need to try and understand how to add my key to it. Sorry about the confusion. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just got my API Key from Google today.

I had to play around with the code, but I am using the exact same routine you are using in your code example above.

It should be noted that you must use SSL to send the request.  https  NOT  http in the following string:

```
strURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml" & _
        "?origin=" & strStartLocation & _
        "&destination=" & strEndLocation & _
        "&sensor=false" & _
        "&units=" & strUnits
```

Here is where I put my API Key and now my application works like it did before I needed the key.

Hope this solves your problem.

================================================

```
APIKey = "Your API Key Here!"

'Send XML request

With objXMLHttp

    .Open "GET", strURL & "&key=" & APIKey, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .send
    objDOMDocument.LoadXML .responseText
End With
```